# Adding Extra Permissions to Facebook Auth in Django

Tags: django, facebook, python-social-auth

My existing app uses [Python Social Auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/facebook.html?highlight=facebook) to allow account creation via Facebook, in addition to creating a custom account. I now want to add the ability to collect the user's email address by adding `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']` to my settings file.

But how does this affect existing accounts? If someone has already logged-in with Facebook (meaning they already have an account with my app) when I didn't ask to access their email, what happens now that they come back to the app? Will I be able to get their email?

Comment: You need to send them through the login flow again, only then will they be asked for the new additional permission. (But probably that is happening already anyway, because server-side apps can only detect if a user is logged in by sending them to the login dialog – if they are logged in and no additional permissions are asked, it’ll redirect right back; otherwise, it’ll ask the user to login/for the additional permissions.)

Comment: thank you @CBroe that's what I was hoping would happen but wasn't sure if either it would 'break' existing accounts or if I would need to configure something else

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe answered my question: 
You need to send them through the login flow again, only then will they be asked for the new additional permission. (But probably that is happening already anyway, because server-side apps can only detect if a user is logged in by sending them to the login dialog – if they are logged in and no additional permissions are asked, it’ll redirect right back; otherwise, it’ll ask the user to login/for the additional permissions.)